# Implementing incremental search in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to implement an incremental search in MySQL. That search will be from left to right.

I have the following data in MySQL.

Test database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d23e0/1

Scenario:

```
+-------+
| code  |
+-------+
| 0412  |
| 05412 |
| 1412  |
| 20412 |
| 28412 |
| 30412 |
| 34120 |
| 34121 |
| 34122 |
| 37412 |
| 40412 |
| 412   |
| 41412 |
| 4412  |
| 47412 |
| 52412 |
```

I want to retrieve all the codes that have a '4' in it. Codes should be returned in the following order. First all codes that have a '4' in first position then '4' in second position and so on.
The output should be:

```
+-------+
| code  |
+-------+
| 40412 |
| 412   |
| 41412 |
| 4412  |
| 47412 |
| 0412  |
| 1412  |
| 34120 |
| 34121 |
| 34122 |
| 05412 |
| 20412 |
| 28412 |
| 30412 |
| 37412 |
| 52412 |
```

Edit: I have modified requirement.

Comment: What will be the maximum length of Code? Is it fixed? or can't predict?

Comment: @Crazy2crack These are ICD9 codes so length varies from 3 to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql has  SUBSTRING_INDEX which returns the substring on the given column based on the delimiter given.
You can perform an order operation by using this.
For both the scenarios you listed, you can use the following query,

```
SELECT code
FROM icd9_codes
WHERE code LIKE '%4%'
ORDER BY LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '4', 1))
```

Comment: this does not work. It just returns all the result no matter if it has '4' in it or not

Comment: Hey i edited the sql query, check if the new one works

Comment: Added one more order by on code to return the codes in correct order

Comment: Why this answer have been downvoted? This matches my new requirement

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is the solution to the original problem which was changed (because nobody was getting it right...myself included).

Original requirement: Return only those codes that have '4' in the first position if there are no such codes then return codes that have '4' in second place and so on..

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d23e0/24

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.digitGroup, t1.thePosition
FROM
(
    SELECT code,
        CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(code) >= 1 AND SUBSTRING(code, 1, 1) = '4' THEN 1
         WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(code) >= 2 AND SUBSTRING(code, 2, 1) = '4' THEN 2
         WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(code) >= 3 AND SUBSTRING(code, 2, 1) = '4' THEN 3
         WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(code) >= 4 AND SUBSTRING(code, 2, 1) = '4' THEN 4
         WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(code) >= 5 AND SUBSTRING(code, 2, 1) = '4' THEN 5
    ELSE 0
    END AS digitGroup,
    POSITION('4' IN code) AS thePosition
    FROM icd9_codes
) t1
WHERE t1.digitGroup > 0 AND t1.digitGroup =
    (
        SELECT MIN(t2.theMin) FROM
            (
                SELECT CASE WHEN POSITION('4' IN code) = 0 THEN 5
                    ELSE POSITION('4' IN code)
                    END AS theMin
                FROM icd9_codes
            ) t2
    )
```

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal Please review this answer.  It has been tested and works.

Comment: This works!! I know you will be unhappy as I have changed my requirement. (

Comment: For future reference please don't change your requirements mid-way.

Comment: I know that sucks really. Thanks for your efforts. I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: If you want to create a SQL Fiddle for this, I can include the link in my answer.

Comment: I think for sravan_kumar's answer with POSITION in where clause will be better. Right? There are we are doing substring and then.

Comment: It all depends on what your requirements are.  That answer appears to meet your new requirements, so from this point of view it is "better."